# How to Update a function after 'n' amount of time?

Tags: solidity, tokens

I am trying to update the amount of tokens minted after 'n' amount of time.  For example every 90 days the token will be minted 20% less.  In my code here i am trying to test it using seconds instead of days and it doesnt seem to like it.

```
    /**
     * Function that add new tokens to the network
     * returns bool to indicate if it was successful
     */
    function trigger() external isAuthorized returns (bool) {
        uint256 bp = 8000; // bp = 8000 = 20% reduction of minted tokens
        if(totalSupply() < 1000000000){
        
            if(initialTime  >= initialTime + 90 seconds && initialTime  < initialTime + 180 seconds){
                tokensPerBlock = initalTokenPB * bp / 10000;
            }
            else if(initialTime  >= initialTime + 180 seconds){
                initalTokenPB = tokensPerBlock;
                initialTime = 180 seconds;
            }
            bool res = readyToMint();
            if(res == false) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                mintTokens();
                return true;
            }
            
        }
    }
```

It doesnt seem to recognize when 90 seconds has passed or even more than 180 seconds in order to update the minting rate and update the initial time.  In the constructor the initial time is 0.

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should set the initialTime in the constructor to the current time `initialTime= block.timestamp`

Then, when `trigger()` is invoked, determine whether the current time is n days beyond the initial time `block.timestamp-initialTime>=N day`

The only thing you need to notice is the units. `block.timestamp` indicates the current time in seconds